# How to count all time users by signup week?

Tags: sql

I think what I am trying to do is probably super simple. My use of SQL is just different until now.

I have a list of accounts that are opened all time. I would like to count how many accounts are opened by week. Monday-Sunday. Since the start of tracking.

```
Account | Signup Date
---------------------
1       | 1/1/17
2       | 1/6/17
3       | 1/10/17
4       | 1/13/17
5       | 2/4/17
6       | 2/5/17
7       | 3/15/17
```

So ideally if every week of the year starting 1/1/17 is numbered 1-53 I would love to be able to get 1 count of how many accounts signed up each week.

If that possible I would love any help.

Comment: Sorry its my first time posting here. I messed up the formatting on the table.

Comment: What [tag:rdbms] are you using?

Comment: do you need to split the results by year too? you should tag the database being used.

Comment: extract the week number from the date, and group by that, counting the accounts.

If you want to have week nr that transcends years, get a monday date somewhere in the past, cast it to date, then subtract it from the signup date and the floor of the division to 7 will be the week number.

Comment: @Mureinik Sorry most of my knowledge is self taught so far so i dont know which exactly it is. I am using google bigquery is that helps?

Comment: @vkp I am building a dashboard so long term eventually would need it separated by year as well. But for now, just need for this year.

Answer (score 0):

the mysql function `week(date)` will help you. Or the SQLServer `DATEPART( wk, date)`

```
SELECT week(Signup Date,3) as 'Week',
    count(Account) as 'Accounts Created'  
FROM table
GROUP BY week(Signup Date,3)
```

Shoud give you the desired result

Comment: Thanks, I will give this a try and see what I can come up with!